# How to deserialize polymorphic classes?

Tags: c++, serialization, polymorphism

I have abstract base class `User` which is inherited by `Student` and `Professor`. `User` have virtual functions for writing in file (serializing) which is overridden in derived classes.

```
void Student::write(std::ofstream& ofs) const {
    ofs << typeid(*this).raw_name() << id << "," << get_name() << "," << get_surname() << ",";
}

void Professor::write(std::ofstream& ofs) const {
    ofs << typeid(*this).raw_name() << title << "," << get_name() << "," << get_surname() << ",";
}
```

It also has function for reading from file (deserialization). The problem is, when I read `typeid(*this).raw_name()` from file, I don't know how to access `Student` or `Professor` so I can instantiate one of those. I'm using template data structure class, so I can't check that explicitly.

```
    template <typename T>
    class UndirectedGraph { ...

        void for_each_DFS(int vertex, const std::function<void(const T&)>& func) const {
            for (const auto value : *nodes.at(vertex))
                func(value);
        }

        void for_each_DFS(int vertex, const std::function<void(T&)>& func) {
            for (auto value : *nodes[vertex])
                func(value);
        }

        virtual void write(std::ofstream& ofs) const override {
            if (std::is_pointer<T>::value)
                for_each_DFS(0, [&ofs](const T& obj) { ofs << *obj; });
            else
                for_each_DFS(0, [&ofs](const T& obj) { ofs << obj; });
        }

        virtual void read(std::ifstream& ifs) override {
            std::string type;
            for_each_DFS(0, [&ifs](T& obj) { 
                // here I get that info, but how do I use it do declare type of derived class?
                std::getline(ifs, type, ','); 
                ifs >> obj;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need a factory function like this: `std::unique_ptr<User*> create_user(const std::string& type);`, the implementation is a series of `if`, then the `User` instance can complete its parsing

Comment: This is actually pretty complex topic. I'd go with some static metadata in every derived class (name string, create-object-function and delete-object-function) and some static metadata in base class (vector of pointers to derived metadata). Then I would search through base class metadata to find create-function. `auto name = ReadName(...); auto metadata = Base::GetMetadata(name); auto * obj = metadata->createObj(); obj->read(...);`

Comment: polymorphic objects are hard to serialize because they are, by nature, not value types. If you want to treat them like values you have to encapsulate them in type erased clases that behave like values. once you have done that you will have a good idea how serialize them. see Sean Parent’s Inheritance is the base class of Evil. Having said that, Boost.Serialization does heroic efforts to serialize through polymorphic pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) and [`std::type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index).

```
#include <any>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>

class A {};
class B {};

template<typename T>
std::string write(){
    static const std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::string> kTypeNames{{typeid(A), "A"}, {typeid(B), "B"}};
    return kTypeNames.at(typeid(T));
}

std::any read(const std::string& s){
   if(s == "A") return A{};
   if(s == "B") return B{};
   return {};
}
```